# I got an error while using selenium ,when I send values to the input field it starts sending in wrong order

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

when I'm sending values to the input field while using selenium, it sends values correctly up to 13 characters but when the value is greater than 13 characters it starts sending in something like reverse order.
My code is:

```
for character in Email:
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(Email)
    actions.click()
    actions.send_keys(character)
    actions.perform()
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2,0.5))
```

it prints in the following order :

```
waseem009@ya.mocooh
```

and my input is :

```
waseem009@yahoo.com
```

it sends correctly till waseem009@yah and after sending character "h", the cursor shifts between characters "a" and "h", and then the output is as above.

```
Website: https://www.easypost.com/signup
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the exact issue, but as a workaround use pyperclip :

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('waseem009@yahoo.com')
```

and now it's in you **clipboard**, you can `paste` in `send_keys()`

```
 actions.send_keys(pyperclip.paste())
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess:  move_to_element() moves the mouse to the center of the element. Then click() moves the input-position cursor to that screen position, which is sometimes in the middle of your already-entered text. It seems to me you'll need to redesign this.